# iOS 7 - UIPickerView over UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uipickerview

I can't find anything else on the internet about this specific topic. Everyone else wants to know how to do inline UIPickerView, but there is nothing on just having a UIPickerView appear over a table.

I have a TableView with a bunch of populated cells. I also have a defunct button in the top left of the screen. What I want is to be able to press the button, bring up a Picker and sort the TableView's cells based on what is selected.

I've been looking around and trying for ages and I just can't find anything detailing a solution to my problem.

Comment: Please post code that you tried.  Make sure to indicate whether the view controller is a table view controller.

Comment: Well, the view controller is indeed a Table View Controller. However, I can't post any code I've tried because there is no code I've tried. I honestly don't know where to start.

Comment: Jam. It's better for you you'll try something before you pop up a question here. Usually the guys who ask without any code get a bunch of down votes. At least do some scatches. Your question is unclear, and if I got your idea right, theres a lot of ways to implement it.

Comment: Agree with @NathFur.  To start, replace the UITableViewController with a UIViewController containing a table.  That's the only way you can have sibling views for the table.  Next, practice by allocating, framing and adding a UIView to the view controller's self.view.  Once you can do that, you can change to a picker view.

Comment: dahn is right. this is the way. also you should use notifications (probably) or delegates if you want the parent window to know about the changes you generated on child window.

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [ActionSheetPicker-3.0](https://github.com/skywinder/ActionSheetPicker-3.0)

It makes it easy to present a UIPickerView over your current view without having to use a delegate as it uses callback blocks.

Comment: Ok, I'll take a look at it